# C++ 11 thread_local and "foreign" threads

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread, thread-local-storage

I would like to use C++ 11 `thread_local`, but our application embeds a JVM, and sometimes C++ methods are called from Java-created thread via JNI. This is essentially the same problem as if an external "C" library created a thread and called back into my C++ code. Is the behavior of `thread_local` variables defined under these circumstances?  Is there any way for my code to compensate for the unexpected appearance of a foreign thread? What about destruction on thread exit?

EDIT: The fact that C++ is being called from a JVM thread via JNI isn't really the central point.  *Any* foreign thread (not created by `std::thread` or `main()`) will have the same issue, presumably.

EDIT: The JVM that I am interested is the OpenJDK (nee Oracle) x64 implementations on Windows and Linux (Ubuntu and RedHat)

Comment: The question really whether 1) there are two distinct base thread libraries used 2) whether two different thread lib can cooperate. I guess the answer is: it depends!

Comment: Yes!  I think there are several distinct questions (1) is compatibility guaranteed by the standard somehow (2) failing that, does it happen to work on the JVMs I care about (3) will it keep working or will it break unexpectedly at some Java or C++ update

Comment: I was asking myself exactly the same question (Java thread calling into C++ method using thread_local via JNI on Win/Linux) right now. Did you ever find out?

Comment: I just created a small test (Win 2010, VC++ 2019; C++ 17) with a static thread_local member variable in a C++ class, calling static init() and get() methods from two Java threads with different values. That worked. I'm impressed.

Comment: Later, maybe. I can't say anything about the behavior on thread exit yet (my thread_locals were just a bunch of SIMD vector classes from the [VCL](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2) library which don't have a destructor). Also, I haven't tested on Linux / gcc yet. I was interested in the performance difference thread_locals make compared to a static variable in that scenario. Combined with the JNI overhead it's too high for my use case (random number generators from the xorshift family). But anyway, it was interesting and I've learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code in jni. Then you use special compiler to compile your c++ code.

In example android can call c++ functions based on NDK. 
And there is special compiler to compile c++ code. If the code is compiled then the function and implementation exists in this compiler.

If external "C" library created a thread and called back into my C++ code. The thread implementation on my c++ site would be windows or Linux, based on workstation. The implementation will call specific code windows or Linux to get what I want. Like fopen in c or std::fstream open. It will call implementation implemented in compiler. In Linux open in windows some winapi call.

Therefore it should work if it is implemented.

Comment: Hi Michal... I realize that JNI allows interop between Java and C++ via native methods, null I don't understand what this has to do with thread_local initialization or cleanup.  My question is "will thread_local variables be usable by threads that were not created by std::thread" (or main, which is a special case treated the same by C++).

Comment: Thread is thread. If there is implementation in c++ then it should be usable.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  While it *may* be true that a congruent implementation of the underlying thread mechanism implies compatibility with thread_local, it is not *necessarily* true.  The thread itself, and thread_local construct/destruct timing do not necessarily go together.

Comment: While that is true. And that destruction/creation is dependent on Java in this case. thread_local is like static object but only in our thread. The local and another thread can save object in it to static duration time. But only our thread will see our object and another thread oder object like static std::map<threadid, object to save>[our thread id]. We can have datarace when we delete thread before it ends. Or we end thread by exit(0).

Answer (score 0):

The question comes down to the implementation of the vm, and the implementation of c++11. There are many combinations, as well this concept of foreign thread is not well defined in your question. If I may scope my answer to foreign meaning pthread, and vm meaning android, then the answer is yes. [this llvm source for stdcxx thread](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/thread) uses pthreads to implement thread. Your question doesn't directly state which VM you are interested in. Some android VM impementations (again, there are many) use pthread for threading, here is a bit of a dated example, [eclair](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/eclair-release/vm/Native.c)

Comment: I realize that JNI threads are native threads, but that doesn't really answer the question of whether thread_local will be initialized or cleaned up properly for threads created in a way other than std::thread.

Comment: see my edit to my answer, I press enter and SO requires text after committing text.

Comment: I googled "std::thread source" and found another example https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/thread#L24